# Duplicating a directory skeleton - Only folders and file names, but not file contents

Tags: filesystems, directory, file-copy

I want to duplicate a folder and all the subfolders, but I do not want to duplicate the contents of the files in this directory.

Let's say the folder I want to duplicate is

```
Folder0
     Folder00
          File000.x      1GB
          File001.x      500MB
     Folder01
          File010.x      600MB
```

I want to create a duplicate that is like

```
Folder0
     Folder00
          File000.x      1KB
          File001.x      1KB
     Folder01
          File010.x      1KB
```

How would you advise I go about this?

Alternatively, I can first create a regular duplicate of the folder, and then scrub the contents of each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find:

```
find src/ -type d -exec mkdir -p dest/{} \; \
       -o -type f -exec touch dest/{} \;
```

Find directory (`-d`) under (`src/`) and create (`mkdir -p`) them under `dest/` or (`-o`) find files (`-f`) and `touch` them under `dest/`.

This will result in:

```
dest/src/<file-structre>
```

You can user `mv` creatively to resolve this issue.

---

Other (partial) solution can be achieved with rsync:

```
rsync -a --filter="-! */" sorce_dir/ target_dir/
```

The trick here is the `--filter=RULE` option that excludes (`-`) everything that is not (`!`) a directory (`*/`)